# Consume Internal API from Razor Page

Tags: c#, json, api, razor-pages, twilio-api

I have an API Controller that makes an API call to Twilio to get a JSON list of messages.

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class MessagingController : TwilioController
{
    //private readonly TwilioClient _client;
    private readonly TwilioAccountDetails _twilioAccountDetails;

    public MessagingController(IOptions<TwilioAccountDetails> twilioAccountDetails)
    {
     
        _twilioAccountDetails = twilioAccountDetails.Value ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(twilioAccountDetails));
        TwilioClient.Init(_twilioAccountDetails.AccountSid,_twilioAccountDetails.AuthToken);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetMessages()
    {
        var message = MessageResource.Read(
                limit: 20
                );
         
        return Ok(message);
    }

}
```

I want to consume the GetMessages method in a Razor Page cshtml.cs file. This is where I will deserialize the JSON data into a list of objects and display them in the Razor Page.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel

{
    public List<InMessage> Messages { get; set; }
    public string responseContent { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:32770/");
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        response = await client.GetAsync("api/Messaging/GetMessages");
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //deserialize JSON here.
            responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Page();
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Can you make an Http request. Below, how to do it in the simplest way:

```
public string responseContent { get; set; }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("<API_BASE_ADDRESS_HERE>");
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        response = await client.GetAsync("api/Messaging/GetMessages");
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //deserialize JSON here.
            responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Page();
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

In the Razor Page .cshtml file you can display the content as follows:

```
<p>@Model.responseContent</p>
```

This is a quick way to solve your problem, but you need to find a way to make it more structured in your application, with services, etc.

I hope this has helped you!

Comment: I've updated the post using your response as a reference. This gives me: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: Please send more details about the structure of your project. Assuming the base address  of the API is correct, it appears that there is a problem with the port. Are you running in a container?